# Starting a proof with inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have the following problem.

> For $m<n$ where both are positive integers. Show that $$\frac{1}{m^k} \binom{m}{k} < \frac{1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k} \leq \frac{1}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$ for $k=2, \dots, m$.

The last line leads me to believe that I should attempt this via a proof by induction, however, I'm not sure where I would start for this. Any hint as to how I should attack this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should prove these inequalities separately. In particular, the second and third inequality are fairly well-known in the form $\binom nk \le \frac{n^k}{k!}$ and $k! \ge 2^{k-1}$. Especially the last one is doable by induction, but another technique you should consider is proving $A \le B$ by factoring the ratio $\frac AB$ into factors that are all at most $1$.

Comment: I was able to prove the 2nd and 3rd inequality directly and by induction respectively. How should I start for the first?

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality amounts to saying that $f(n) = \frac1{n^k} \binom nk$ is an increasing function of $n$. So rather than compare $f(m) < f(n)$ for all $m<n$, it's enough to check that $f(n)<f(n+1)$ holds.

Between $\frac1{n^k} \binom nk$ and $\frac1{(n+1)^k} \binom{n+1}{k}$, many factors are in common: $\binom nk = \frac{n-k}{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k}$. To control the remaining factors, it may help to use [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) that $(1+x)^r \ge 1 + rx$ when $x \ge -1$ and $r$ is a nonnegative integer.